# ngx-bootstrap datepicker - disable specific days

Tags: angular, bootstrap-datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I am using v2.0.1 of ngx-bootstrap in my project.
I am trying to configure the **datepicker** to disable certain days.
The config option is dayDisabled.
This feature was implemented in v2.0.0 of ngx-bootstrap.
https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/pull/2744/files
The way I am implementing it is not picking it up.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
      <input
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Datepicker"
        bsDatepicker
        [bsConfig]="{ dayDisabled: '[0,1,2,3]', containerClass: 'theme-red' }">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it is [not implemented in the newer versions](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/4145) of ngx-bootstrap.

Comment: when can we expect it to be around

Comment: This is not working with ` "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",` can you have relavent answer with it.Can you please help.. I want to disable some days from calendar in datepicker.. @OneXer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BsDatepickerConfig`:

`dayDisabled: [0, 1, 2]` into `bsConfig`

or

`dayDisabled: '[0,1,2,3]' = dayDisabled: [0,1,2,3]`

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#themes

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BsDatepickerConfig } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-datepicker-color-theming',
  templateUrl: './color-theming.html'
})
export class DemoDatepickerColorThemingComponent {
  colorTheme = 'theme-green';

  bsConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;

  applyTheme(pop: any) {
    // create new object on each property change
    // so Angular can catch object reference change
    this.bsConfig = Object.assign({}, { containerClass: this.colorTheme, dayDisabled: [0, 1, 2] });
    setTimeout(() => {
      pop.show();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working with ` "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",` can you have relavent answer with it.Can you please help.. I want to disable some days from calendar in datepicker.. @Nancy Maturana